# What was Brad Pitt's character's motivation to not take cover in Fury?

Tags: ending, fury

Why did the Fury's commander (played by Pitt) continue to expose himself with the .50 cal on the turret when he knew there was a sniper out there? His gunner had just had his head taken off and he himself had been hit in the shoulder. Was it a case of not wanting to surrender to a Waffen-SS unit or was it just movie melodrama, or maybe a bit of both?

(I would have dressed everyone in German uniform, from the dead, to confuse the attacking force and gathered all weapons including stick grenades inside and under the tank. Molotov cocktails might have been made and the remaining fuel siphoned and drained around the tank - to be lit in case of a night assault by the Germans. A pit would have been dug under the tank to provide a defensible position if all upstairs was lost. The commander and bow gunner could have hid in this pit with all hatches locked from the inside and used the weapons stashed there if necessary after the sniper appeared.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have observed the movie closely you can see that, he has seen so much death that he is not afraid to die, but he is afraid to die not in his home which is his tank. He says near the end of the movie "if I die is better to die in my home" he refers to the tank. That's the motivation for not taking cover even though enemy troops are on their way.

Answer (score 0):

You've also had several hours (and no stress) to devise an alternate plan.

As I recall, there wasn't really much chance of escape.  They had to hunker down and get the job done, and it wasn't just for themselves.  There were other troops that could be at risk if they failed.  At that point, you're thinking about taking out as many people as possible so your platoon has less people to worry about, and you're just hoping you can take out 10 or 20 people before you get snuffed.  A 20:1 kill ratio is insanely high, actually.  But it's Hollywood, so why not.

Answer (score -2):

I have not seen the movie, but if I could guess it would be because he either thought he could kill the sniper, though I doubt that, or so that the rest of his unit, if there were any left (again, have not seen the film), could escape to better cover as the sniper would be hiding so as to not take a .50 cal round to the face. As a commander, he may also have felt that he was responsible for the lives of his unit.

Or it could have been so the director could have more shooting, because why not.